# how to insert dummy rows in sql without using insert query?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, union

I have the following query

```
select '2016' as yr,warehouse as product,sum(answertext) p1 ,
round((sum(abc)/(select sum(abc) from [table 1])*100),2) p2
 from [table 1]
group by warehouse
order by p1 desc
limit 10
```

which is showing the following output

```
yr        product            prodnum    prodper

2016     Harness Extra      94427        10.4
2016     Lumax              54534         9.6
.. 
... 
..
...
..
..
..
2016   Capreno              534533        4.6
```

**now i have to manually insert dummy values  for yr 2015 and 2014  with custom values for prdonum and prodper which i have in another word sheet
how to do it in a single query ?  any help would be great?
it should be in the following format**

```
    yr      product              prodnum      prodper

    2016   Harness Extra         94427       10.4  // from table
    2015   Harness Extra         32453       5.7  <- custom value to be inserted
    2014   Harness Extra         21215       2.3  <- custom value to be inserted
    2016   Lumax                 78994       8.76  // from table
    2015   Lumax                 43435       4.77 <- custom value to be inserted
    2014   Lumax                 15522       3.55 <- custom value to be inserted
    ..
    ..


    ..
<totally 30 rows>
```

Comment: Create help table containing all possible years. Outer join with that table.

Answer (score 0):

If you have it in another table, maybe use a union statement?

```
Select * from 
 (
select '2016' as yr,warehouse as product,sum(answertext) p1 ,
round((sum(abc)/(select sum(abc) from [table 1])*100),2) p2
         from [table 1]
        group by warehouse

UNION ALL            

    select '2015' as yr,warehouse as product,sum(answertext) p1 ,
    round((sum(abc)/(select sum(abc) from [table 1])*100),2) p2
     from [table 2]
    group by warehouse

    UNION ALL

    select '2014' as yr,warehouse as product,sum(answertext) p1 ,
    round((sum(abc)/(select sum(abc) from [table 1])*100),2) p2
     from [table 3]
    group by warehouse
    )a
 order by p1 desc
```

Comment: its showing the error : incorrect use of union and order by

Comment: I've Updated answer